# Type for nested objects with specific leaf types

Tags: typescript, recursive-datastructures

I want a type for nested Objects, that have a specific type at their leaves.

I would expect this to be correct:

```
let a: Leaves<number> = {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": {
        "baz": 2
    }
};
```

and this to fail:

```
let a: Leaves<number> = {
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": {
        "baz": 'something else' // Leaf of type string
    } 
};
```

I tried

```
export type Leaves<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T | Leaves<T>;
}
```

However with that definition both examples give a compilation error. The first one says `Type '{ "foo": number; "bar": number; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a type for a node with arbitrary keys, and values as leaves or    other nodes, [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) is the way to go:

```
export type Leaves<T> = {
    [n: string]: T | Leaves<T>
}
```

(btw I'd rather call it `Node<T>`, not `Leaves<T>`)

Mapped types are not suitable here because mapped type like this

```
{
    [P in keyof T]: T | Leaves<T>;
}
```

can have only the properties that `T` has - that's what `[P in keyof T]:` says. When `T` is `number`, it means that mapped type can have only properties that are in `number` type, and because `number` is primitive it essentially means it's the same as `number`. That's the reason for `not assignable to number` error message - typescript tries to find most descriptive type to show in error message, and in your case it's just `number`.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Guess I was a little confused.